# Stack Array Data Structure using Java

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

I am trying to write a stack code using Java for getting browsing history for 100 data. I wrote this code but I am not sure this program satisfies first in last out rule and also most importantly I don't want to write `lastvisit = browsing.pop();` for 100 times for 100 data. What can I do for it?

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class Browser {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       
        Stack<String> browsing = new Stack<>();

        
        browsing.push("google.com");
        browsing.push("facebook.com");
        browsing.push("twitter.com");
        browsing.push("youtube.com");

        System.out.println("Browsing History " + browsing);
        System.out.println();

        
        String lastvisit = browsing.pop();  
        System.out.println("lastvisit " + lastvisit);
        System.out.println("Browsing History " + browsing);
        System.out.println();

       
        lastvisit = browsing.pop();
        System.out.println("lastvisit " + lastvisit);
        System.out.println("Browsing History " + browsing);
        lastvisit = browsing.pop();  
        System.out.println("lastvisit " + lastvisit);
        System.out.println("Browsing History " + browsing);
    }   
}
```

Comment: A list would make more sense to store a browsing history.

Answer (score 1):

The JDK's `Stack` class indeed implements the "first in last out" (more commonly known as "last in first out", or LIFO) rule.

One way to go over the entire history would be to loop over the stack until it's empty:

```java
while (!browsing.empty()) {
    String lastvisit = browsing.pop();  
    System.out.println("lastvisit " + lastvisit);
    System.out.println("Browsing History " + browsing);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated the code with string array and added @Mureinik 's answer. Final clean code:

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.util.Stack;

public class Browser {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
           List<String> urls = Arrays.asList("facebook.com*mehmet.com+google.com-kesimalioglu.com/youtube.com".split("[\\*+/-]"));

        Stack<String> browsing = new Stack<String>();
    for(String str : urls)
        browsing.add(str);
        
        

        System.out.println("Browsing History " + browsing);
        System.out.println();

        
        while (!browsing.empty()) {
    String lastvisit = browsing.pop();  
    System.out.println("lastvisit " + lastvisit);
    System.out.println("Browsing History " + browsing);
    System.out.println();
}

    }
    
}
```